# How to store checkbox values in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a field 'balcony' in a table which is of `smallint` type.

In the form I used checkbox for Balcony and in the code I declared 'hasbalcony as Boolean'.

When I am trying to insert the value in to table it is saying that:

> 'specified cast is not valid. Make sure that the source type is convertible to the destination type.'
> at the line
> checkboxBackyard.checked = (bool)propertyData.Rows[0]["backyard"];

Comment: Please show the code that inserts the data. And boolean data should be stored in bit fields

Answer (score 2):

In SQL server, you can use [BIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type.

The error you're getting is because you're trying to convert Int to Bool which isn't valid.

If you can't change the data type in SQL server then do a comparison e.g.

```
checkboxBackyard.checked = ((int)propertyData.Rows[0]["backyard"]==1)
```

Comment: Dale, How do I accept?  I do not see checkbox?